# Align microsoft access queries

Tags: ms-access

Each time I have to copy a query from MSAccess from a control's [record source] property and paste in notepad to align it just so I can read it.

I once used Ctrl+R to replace commas with newline characters but now forgot what the newline character is. Have you used this before, if so how can I get the newline character?

Better yet, is there a tool to auto align SQL from MSAccess or any of the Microsoft database tools.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This online service "pretty" formats SQL for you [Pretty SQL formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) or you could try using the [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) replacement for Notepad; this includes a facility to search and replace for "extended" characters and replace them with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

In my [AccdbMerge](https://www.db-merge-tools.net/microsoft-access-diff-merge-overview.html) tool there is a function 'Indent SQL text' which does this trick for the most common query types. Even though this is a diff&merge tool, this feature will work even if you will open only one file, and it is available in the free version.